# Можно ли скачать для своего сайта контрол гугл календаря "Повтор мероприятия"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar, calendar-view

Т е есть ли что то похожее, чтобы можно было встроить в свой код (php, js/jquery) наподобие как встраивается контрол datepicker?
[image: control]